# Unexpected Output for a float variable

Tags: c

I can not understand the output generated by the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float d =245.3;
    char c = 'A';
    printf("d = %f",d);
    d = d+c;
    printf("\nd = %f",d);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

Output:
d = 245.3000003
d = 310.2999988
```

Though d was 245.3, but it is printing 245.3000003.
And after adding 65, it is not accurate.

Comment: welcome to the world of floating point numbers, where nothing is ever what you expect it to be.

Comment: First day of computer studies, you get told this.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: A `float` cannot represent every possible number.   A `float` will represent the a number the best it can which is typically accurate about 1 part in 16,000,000.  `245.3000003` and `245.3` differ by 1 part in 800,000,000

Answer (score 0):

Floating have a precision problem. And the reason is that 0.1 is not perfectly represented with float.

And a good read to start with:- [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf)

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best place to *start*. You might also try section 14 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).